# What are the different texts to learn about Lord Rama?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, itihasa, story

I love hinduism and in that I love reading about Lord Rama and Mata sita. I want to know which other Ramayanas or texts related to Lord Rama are available to us so that I can read them. Can someone please provide a list of all the major scriptures. I would be very grateful.

Note: I have already read the Valmiki Ramayana, Ramacharitamanas, Ramopakhyana and parts of ramayana present in some puranas.

Comment: I would recommend you to check this chapter out: 
Ramanujan, A. (1991). Three Hundred Rāmāyaṇas: Five Examples and Three Thoughts on Translation. In P. Richman (Ed.), *Many Rāmāyaṇas: The Diversity of a Narrative Tradition in South Asia* (pp. 22-49).University of California Press. https://doi.org/10.1525/9780520911758-004 ;

Comment: and of course the book too :
Richman, P. (1991). *Many Rāmāyaṇas: The Diversity of a Narrative Tradition in South Asia*. University of California Press. https://doi.org/10.1525/9780520911758

Comment: There are lots of versions of Rāmāyaṇa than you mentioned and you will find mention of many of those and their content in brief in the above two references. Also, this would be a useful bibliography to search through various Rāmāyaṇas and their critical editions, researches or translations https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/display/document/obo-9780195399318/obo-9780195399318-0166.xml
Note: Oxford bibliography link requires institutional access to browse through the whole bibliography, without access, you won't be able to view the complete bib.

Answer (score 3):

1. [**Shaiva Ramayan**](https://archive.org/details/shaiva-ramayan-with-malini-tika-of-rbs-shiv-sanskrit-sansthan/mode/1up) by Lord Mahadev himself
   (Male version of Adbhut Ramayan - Ram Gita)
2. [**Satyopkhyan**](https://archive.org/details/UcQH_satyopakhyan-by-dr-shailaja-pandey-no.-56-ganga-nath-campus/mode/1up) by Mahrishi Valmiki

If These 2 versions of Ramayan are still present, do check it out :)

Comment: Thank you I will definitely check them out!!!

Comment: Niroj ji what do you mean by (Male version of adbhut ramayana - Rama gita) written within brackets? I did not understood that.

Comment: If you know some more authentic works please let me know..Humble request. Jai Siya Rama

Comment: Like in adbhut Ramayan, maa sita ji slayed thousand headed ravan. But shaiva ramayan is in another kalpa where shri ram slayed thousand headed ravan. Its authentic though